# Write logs into file java.util.logging.Logger

Tags: java, logging, appender

Need code(config file) for writing **logs into a file** using **util.logging.logger**. It should also append the logs to the file from the other classes of the same project.

I know how to do it in log4j but I need it in util.logging.logger. Please help.

log4j file

```
# Set root logger level to DEBUG and its only appender to Appender1.
log4j.rootLogger=info,dailyRoll,console

# Appender1 is set to be a ConsoleAppender.
log4j.appender.console=org.apache.log4j.ConsoleAppender
log4j.appender.console.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
log4j.appender.console.layout.ConversionPattern=%-10d %-4r [%t] %-5p %c %x - %m%n

# Appender2 uses PatternLayout.
log4j.appender.fileAppender=org.apache.log4j.RollingFileAppender    
log4j.appender.fileAppender.file=/home/Application.log
log4j.appender.fileAppender.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
log4j.appender.fileAppender.layout.ConversionPattern=%-10d %-4r [%t] %-5p %c %x - %m%n

# Appender3 uses PatternLayout.
log4j.appender.dailyRoll=org.apache.log4j.DailyRollingFileAppender
log4j.appender.dailyRoll.file=/home/cms/MyFiles/EJBJob/CMS_log/Application.log
log4j.appender.dailyRoll.DatePattern=.yyyy-MM-dd
log4j.appender.dailyRoll.Append=true
log4j.appender.dailyRoll.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
log4j.appender.dailyRoll.layout.ConversionPattern=%-10d %-4r [%t] %-5p %c %x - %m%n
```

I need the configuration file similar to the above one in logging 
(log4j.appender.dailyRoll.file=/home/cms/MyFiles/EJBJob/CMS_log/Application.log)

Comment: Let me google that for you ... http://tutorials.jenkov.com/java-logging/index.html

Comment: @Constantin Thanks. But i need a sample program which would append the logs to files. I use the following in log4j but i need the similar code in logging log4j.appender.fileAppender.file=/home/MyFiles/CMS_log/Application.log

Answer (score 2):

Try using this code:

```
import java.util.logging

// create an instance of Logger at the top of the file, as you would do with log4j
private static final Logger log = Logger.getLogger( ClassName.class.getName() );
FileHandler fh = new FileHandler("your_log.txt", true);   // true forces append mode
SimpleFormatter sf = new SimpleFormatter();
fh.setFormatter(sf);
log.addHandler(fh);

// java.util.logging has several logging levels from which to choose; here are two:
log.log( Level.FINE, "A FINE logging message goes here.");
log.log( Level.SEVERE, "A SEVERE logging message goes here.");
```

Comment: Thanks. I need a code which would append logs to file.

Comment: Correct Thanks, But I have many classes. In each and every classes i cannot declare the FileHandler fh = new FileHandler("your_log.txt", true); right so I need configuation file which will describe all the details.

Answer (score 0):

I think you are looking for this property

```
java.util.logging.FileHandler.append
```

> Sets whether or not the FileHandler's should append to an existing file or not (true or false), if an existing log file is found.

Please hava a look at this [link](http://tutorials.jenkov.com/java-logging/configuration.html#configuration-file)